# How to check OS version using php (script) file

Tags: 14.04, php

I have a Linux Server and only having ftp access for it I want to check Server full detail like OS version, RAM, HDD, installed packages etc is it possible using php script file to get information for the server.?

I tried to get its details using phpinfo.php

```
   <<?php
echo php_uname();
echo PHP_OS;
echo '<br />';
$bytes = disk_free_space(".");
$si_prefix = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB' );
$base = 1024;
$class = min((int)log($bytes , $base) , count($si_prefix) - 1);
echo $bytes . '<br />';
echo sprintf('%1.2f' , $bytes / pow($base,$class)) . ' ' .    $si_prefix[$class] . '<br />';
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 36640
$a = str_repeat("Hello", 4242);
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 57960
unset($a);
echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // 36744
?>
```

It looks like.

```
 Linux fileserver 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:45:15 UTC 2015 i686

26575900672
24.75 GB
117168 138460 117168
```

How we can make it more useful please give your suggestions.

Comment: define "more useful"? http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.php-uname.htm has some options to make it show more specific info. But is that more useful?

Answer (score 1):

You can login on server by putty with same detail (FTP login detail) and run following command:

```
uname -a
```

Or, you can execute PHP shell command to get OS info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shell_exec` which is a PHP function, which runs your shell command and returns the output of it.

See this page as reference: [PHP: shell_exec - Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

So by combining this function and `uname`, `lscpu`, `free` and do little text processing you can get what you want.